# Find Average with user input under condition until user press enter without value

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop, average

I received the code problem to find an average with user input.
Here is the description

**If the user hits enter/return without typing anything, the program stops and prints the average of all the numbers that were given. The average should be given to 2 decimal places.**

To solve this problem, I approached the following code steps:

```
count = 0
number = input("")
sum = 0

while True:
    number
    if number != "":
        sum = sum + int(number)
        count += 1
    else:
        break


print(f"Average is {sum/count}")
```

However, It doesn't out of the loop when I type nothing. Please let me know which part makes this code an infinite loop.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for the input inside the while loop, otherwise, you are asking for it only once without updating its value. You should try with the following:

```
count = 0
sum = 0

while True:
    number = input("")
    if number != "":
        sum = sum + int(number)
        count += 1
    else:
        break


print(f"Average is {sum/count}")
```

As an example here's a quick execution of the code:

```
10 #Entered 10
35 #Entered 35
15 #Entered 15
   #Pressed Enter without typing anything
Average is 20.0
```

Comment: Be careful for the case when the user enters nothing from the first iteration, it perform a division by zero in your code.

Comment: Appreciate it! I thought assigning the input function in a global way would be a much cleaner way. Many thx guys